# iball 3.75G-72 connect mobile broadband USB modem not detected in Ubuntu 12.04. how to detect that modem?

Tags: 12.04, networking, modem

I have bought new iball 3.75g modem to connect with Ubuntu1 2.04. But,Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't detect my device. I have already use Gnome ppp tool to detect my modem. But, the tool couldn't detect my modem and shows error message like "no modem found" . What can I do for this problem? please help me. Its urgent.

I don't find any answer yet. help.

```
siva@siva-XPS-L501X:~$ lsusb

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0408:2fb1 Quanta Computer, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2020:0002
```

Comment: Please post the result of `lsusb` while the modem is connected

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9605
```

Above is the code you should run to use your iBall 3.5G Modem, shame on iBall developers on saying no for something so simple.

It works, just you just have to run this command every time you start your computer

Don't forget to setup network connection before using it.

Answer (score 1):

just in case if there is a new bee who is looking for this information 
following is a step by step method

- Create a mobile broadband connection [choose connect automatically]
- Run the following command:

```
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9605
```

- Run `dmesg` to check the configuration of it, I don't know but it shows whether the above command was a success or not?
- Run `lsusb` to check the usb devices
- If its still not working then disable networking and enable it again.

If you are getting confused with terminal things as I was, do this

```
sudo lsusb -vvv> /tmp/usb_info
```

then,

go to `/tmp/usb_info`
that document will show you, your usb devices and its information.

Answer (score 0):

Official replay from Iball technicalities

> Dear sir,
>
> Thank you for contacting iBall Baton Technical support team.
>
> Sorry to inform you that the 3.5G Modem(2.0 )**will not** work in
>   Ubuntu 12.04 platform.
>
> For any further  technical  queries please be free to contact iBall
>   Baton Tech. support Team
>
> Contact no : 022-67745100/30815100 Email Id       :
>   support@iballbaton.com
>
> For more products detailed information do visit our  website  -
>   http://www.iballbaton.com
>
> Thanks & Regards,
>
> Technical Support Team

But its worked on My Ubuntu 11.04 with some shell scripts!

Comment: do they comment if it works on 11.04 ?
how did you get it to work on 11.04 ?